# Android Activity Indicator + Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I have a Navigation Drawer or Sliding Menubar in Android, and on clicking on the Navigation drawer its makes HTTP request but due to the activity indicator the smoothness of the navigation bar is lost i.e. Sometimes it get Stuck while closing. What should I do to make the Navigation drawer better?

Comment: Why not close the drawer instantly and show the activity indicator in the main view fragment?

Comment: I tried that but did not help. :(

Comment: Can you post the code?